# How to take care of the application before or after .Net framework upgrade in Azure App service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-framework-version

I have few applications developed using different .Net framework and deployed in Azure app service as web app and function app.

The applications developed using Visual Studio 2013 ( I think, .net 4.5.1) and Visual Studio 2019 (.Net 4.6) and deployed in Azure. The application type is ASP.Net MVC, Web app using .Net core and Azure function app.

Very recently MS announced that they are upgrading the .Net framework in Azure App service ( or basically in Azure platform). I think, Which is going to effect after 14 July 2020.

My Questions are, [considering very less time we have and applications are developed in old versions of Visual Studios] ;

1. will all these application work perfectly in Azure app service, after MS upgrade the framework?
2. I hope, the old versions of the .Net framework will still be exists in Azure/Azure app service along with the newly .Net versions?
3. The development PC does not have .net 4.8 version installed, installing, upgrading application's framework and testing the applications in very less time is quite impossible, is there any quick ways to do testing of entire application?
4. Is there any chance that application functionality will not work during this upgrade and there will be a downtime? Any one faced similar issues?
5. These applications are interaction with other enterprise application, what actions to be taken care?
6. Is there any step by steps guideline given by Microsoft those needs to followed?

Is there anyone facing similar issues? What is the best practice/ways to manage this in very less time ? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: DId my answer help solve your issue? If yes, please consider accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the announcement:
https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/06/09/NET-Framework-4.8-is-coming-to-App-Service.html

> The .NET Framework 4.8 update is a non-breaking in-place upgrade on App Service. No updates are required to existing applications.

All frameworks are installed, so you will have no issues. There should not be an extra amount of downtime for the upgrade.

[image: .net frameworks]

Comment: Thank you so much. However, regarding this sentence "In preparation for the platform upgrade to .NET Framework 4.8, customers can choose to test applications locally in advance." -> Is it that customer can just install the .net 4.8 framework in local environment and run the applications in local environment for testing ? There is no need to upgrade the existing application's framework, that is, lets say application framework from 4.5 to 4.8 ?

Comment: I'm sorry, asking all these questions because of,  in the past, for other azure services. That is, in 2018/2019 , whenever, there is IoT hub upgrade, the devices connected created problem.

Comment: Yes, you can install 4.8 locally and see if anything breaks. As long as you don't change your application code, there should be no impact. You can switch to using the new framework version at your own discretion.